# Problem displaying ShapeDrawable in an ImageView

Tags: android

I am writing an app which will create drawable shapes and add them to other drawables. (Think Tetris pieces onto a Tetris board.) As a test, I want to have a particular shape appear when my activity is loaded, but I cannot get a Drawable to appear in the ImageView I created. Could anyone explain why the following code isn't working?

Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

    ShapeDrawable sD = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    sD.setBounds(1,1,10,10);
    sD.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);

    mImg.setImageDrawable(sD);
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="320px"
        android:layout_height="206px"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/debug"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I have been able to make static resources from the 'drawable' folder appear in this ImageView, just not Drawables I have created in the code.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use a simple View and just set its background drawable to the shape using `setBackgroundDrawable`.

The ImageView probably can't display your shape because it has no default size. You can give your shape a default sizer using `sD.setIntrinsicWidth` and `sD.setIntrinsicHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can create your own custom view by extending the view class. I suppose Drawable objects can only be handled from within a custom view. just create and render the drawable in the `onDraw()` method

Comment: although this answer is technically correct, you should not create Objects in the `onDraw()`-Method, but instead create them in theConstructor and reuse or modify them as needed. This is because `onDraw()`is being called in a tight loop at runtime.

Comment: I kind of took it for granted that people will take care of it automatically! :)

Comment: completely understandable, especially since eclipse will generate a warning to that effect.